# Recursive function returning none

Tags: python, function, recursion

Recursive function to sum elements in a list is returning **None**

```
def recsum(l,sum=0):
    sum += l[0]
    l = l[1:]
    if l:recsum(l,sum)
    else: return sum

val = [2,3,4,5]

print(recsum(val))
```

Output

> > > None

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the function when you call it from inside itself:

```
def recsum(l,sum=0):
    sum += l[0]
    l = l[1:]
    if l:
        return recsum(l,sum)
    else: 
        return sum
```

Comment: I didnt understand this... Where is the recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
when `l` was non-empty then function was returning `None`
so just adding a return statement resolved the issue

```
def recsum(l,sum=0):
    sum += l[0]
    l = l[1:]
    if l:return recsum(l,sum)
    else: return sum

val = [2,3,4,6]

print(recsum(val))
```

Output: 15

Comment: Hey. I did a similar answer but was not able to replicate your solution on my code... Where is the recursion? Why are u returning the function? This isnt clear to me. Sorry.